# Real time updates for mobile apps

Tags: android, ios, mobile

Im working on a mobile application and i'm trying to incorporate real time updates. I'm trying to get a sense of my options available to me and what the community thinks is a good solution. I've been considering just consuming an API using some type of polling technique to receive server side updates, but i feel like there is a better solution. Basically I'm trying to figure out a solution where the server can push notifications to a native mobile app.

Thanks guys

Comment: While there's a lot of APIs out there that may make some parts easier-  in the end they're all polling, either they poll a URL or they keep a TCP socket open and wait for data to appear on it.  The APIs just do some of the leg work for you.

Comment: Makes sense. I guess what im trying to get at is would continously consuming an API every 3 seconds or so be the solution, or perhaps holding a tcp socket connection open for a greater length of time?

Comment: Holding the TCP socket open would be better.  Pinging a webservice every 3 seconds could cause a couple of problems.  The first is out of order return of results.  The second is horrible battery life (the TCP socket will effect that too, but it will only actively send when it needs a keep alive.  Active sending costs more juice).  Of course a special socket and protocol takes more engineering effort.

Answer (score 0):

You could use C2DM (Cloud to Device Messaging). Instead of polling the server every so often, this method pushes information to the clients when it is ready.

For a good tutorial, see here: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html